# Show JSON data in grid in vaadin

Tags: java, mysql, json, vaadin

Am a new bee to vaadin. I have to show the data from a JSON file (which is fetching from MySQL db) in Grid/Table(vaadin). I am able show the data in table if JSON in the below format.

```
[
{
"id": "ex-wardrobe",
"productId": "ex-wardrobe",
"name": "exWardrobe",
"desc": "Some description",
"dimension": "WxDxH 148\" X 24\" X 112\" ",
"category": "Bedroom",
"subcategory": "Wardrobe",
"categoryId": "bedroom",
"subcategoryId": "wardrobe",
"tags": "all, Space Design Bedroom, Space Details Wardrobe",
"designer": "hb",
"curr": "INR",
"popularity": "1",
"relevance": "1",
"shortlisted": "1",
"likes": "1",
"createDt": "",
"pageId": "ex-wardrobe",
"styleName": "Fresh",
"styleId": "cfresh",
"priceRange": "Premium",
"priceId": "premium",
"defaultPrice": "123",
"defaultMaterial": "MDF ",
"defaultFinish": "LAMINATE"
  }
]
```

But, if i get JSON(data is related to same product) in the below format am unable to add data in table.

```
[
 {
 "id": "ex-wardrobe",
"productId": "ex-wardrobe",
"name": "exWardrobe",
"desc": "Some description",
"dimension": "WxDxH 148\" X 24\" X 112\" ",
"category": "Bedroom",
"subcategory": "Wardrobe",
"categoryId": "bedroom",
"subcategoryId": "wardrobe",
"tags": "all, Space Design Bedroom, Space Details Wardrobe",
"designer": "hb",
"curr": "INR",
"popularity": "1",
"relevance": "1",
"shortlisted": "1",
"likes": "1",
"createDt": "",
"pageId": "ex-wardrobe",
"styleName": "Fresh",
"styleId": "cfresh",
"priceRange": "Premium",
"priceId": "premium",
"defaultPrice": "123",
"defaultMaterial": "MDF ",
"defaultFinish": "LAMINATE",
"mf": [
  {
    "basePrice": "123",
    "material": "MDF ",
    "finish": "LAMINATE"
  }
],
"images": [
  "066___ex_WARDROBE_Dim.jpg",
  "067___ex_WARDROBE_close_door.jpg",
  "068___ex_DOVE_dim.jpg"
],
"components": [],
"accessories": []
 }
 ]
```

This is the code which am using to show JSON data in table,

```
    Table grid = new Table();
    root.addComponent(grid);
    grid.setStyleName("iso3166");
    grid.setPageLength(6);
    grid.setSizeFull();
    grid.setSelectable(true);
    grid.setMultiSelect(false);
    grid.setImmediate(true);
    grid.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
    grid.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
   try {
       JSONArray products = productsDataProvider.getCatalogs();
        JsonContainer dataSource = 
       JsonContainer.Factory.newInstance(products.toString());
        grid.setContainerDataSource(dataSource);
        grid.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
       grid.setWidth("98%");
        grid.addStyleName(ChameleonTheme.TABLE_STRIPED);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {

    }
    grid.setWidth("100%");
    grid.setHeight("100%");
    root.addComponent(grid);
```

Am stuck on this and i have sleepless night on this. Million tons of thanks in advance. I hope you GURU's can help me in this :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not vaadin expert. See it first time and like it. I guess your problem are the arrays inside your object. I mean this:

```
"mf": [
  {
    "basePrice": "173881",
    "material": "MDF ",
    "finish": "LAMINATE"
  }
],
"images": [
  "066___ex_WARDROBE_Dim.jpg",
  "067___ex_WARDROBE_close_door.jpg",
  "068___ex_DOVE_dim.jpg"
],
"components": [],
"accessories": []
```

No idea how the component should display this. Have you tried it without mf, images, components and accessories?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, That's why i posted here.. if i remove mf,images,components and accessories. data is displayed in table upto  default finish. But i need those four arrays also :(

Comment: Looked at the API and it's not possible. They can deal with sub-objects but not with arrays. In that case you would insert a new Grid inside of a Grid Item. To do the Grid have to support plugins for items they display.

[DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) can do that. But not sure you want use this.

Comment: Why not. It's all just JS.

Comment: Not really. The most grids are overloaded and take too much performance. Grid are not responsive anyway and in most! cases give no better clarity. I always avoid the usage of grids. The usage of inline blocks is more effective. Blocks are clear, can be structured more easily and filter and design as to show the user the data better.

Comment: As am new to vaadin, i don't know how to use datatables in vaadin. I used datatables in html pages(jsp's) when am using spring. But i am very new here

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very simple JSONContainer. As can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/tehapo/JsonContainer/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/teemu/jsoncontainer/IndexedJsonContainer.java), this implementation does not support nested / compound elements and arrays.

First you have to ask yourself how these complex objects need to be displayed (UX), especially the "mf" field.

**UPDATE**

Simple compound objects (like `"simpleCompound": {"name": "foo", number: 123}`) can be shown in a table column (not supported by the JSONContainer you use, but similar functionality is available by the `BeanItemContainer`, so look there for how to implement this functionality).

The array fields are more problematic from a UX standpoint. Mostly this information is only shown on demand or in separate panels. The Vaadin `Grid` component offers the possibility to show a details view, see [the wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36). Maybe that will fit your requirements.

Comment: Yes, i am stuck there. i don't know how to show the complex objects in table. if you have any solution, please help me out

Comment: Is there any BeanItemContainer example for JSON in GIT?

Comment: Not that i know. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Currently nested json data is not supported unless you create your own advance template for that. There is currently an [online json container application demo](http://teemu.virtuallypreinstalled.com/JsonContainer) that is used to test if the data is really json or json array but not nested. Then it displays that data in grid table. So you can use this to verify your data.

You can also get the application template with source code on [github](https://github.com/tehapo/JsonContainer-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/teemu/jsoncontainer/demo/JsonContainerDemo.java)